# BeautifulSoup extract text from all div class including children elements

Tags: class, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to extract from a website all the text divided by div and class.
I'd like to keep this tool generic to use it with different websites.

The piece of code below is working fine. But I don't know how to get into the children elements.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'xxx'
        
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")
div = soup.find_all("div")

classes = [value
    for element in soup.find_all(class_=True)
    for value in element["class"]]

for class_el in classes:
    try:
        div = soup.find('div', {"class" : class_el})
        text = div.text
        print("")
        print("=============================")
        print(class_el)
        print("")
        print(text)

    except: 
        print("error")
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way "to keep this tool generic"; websites are very different from each other. If you supply a sample url, an answer may be found for that specific site.

Comment: Got it; and what exactly is your expected output from that url?

Comment: For all the elements of the list "classes", I'd like to extract the corresponding text if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should get you the text, if any, from each `<div>` element in the soup, if that `<div>` element has one of the classes which is in the `classes` list.

As an aside, it's not a good idea to name your variables `div`, etc., so I changed that part a bit:

```
for class_el in classes:    
        target = soup.find('div', {"class" : class_el})
        if target is not None and len(target.text.strip())>0:
            print(target.text.strip())
            print('=============')
```

Comment: Thanks that's helpful. But is it possible to go deeper into the tree? For example I'd like to grab the text in <div class="one-half first"> and all the other div at the same level.

Comment: @user1564140 I'm not really sure what you mean. Can you edit your question (not in a comment) and give a few examples of what you want to grab?

Comment: ok, actually there was a bug because of white spaces in the names of classes. I guess that caused a misunderstanding.